Symfony and LexikJWT - Session was used while the request was declared stateless
I have a problem with Symfony 7.0.6 and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle 2.20.3.
Introduction
My application is divided into 3 parts (/bundles):

Front (everything related to classic users)
Admin (everything related to admin users)
API (everything related to the API)

I use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle for the API authentication.

Issue
I have a custom provider to authenticate API users.
When I try to access a public route in my API (for example /api/login), I don't get any error and the API returns a JWT token. If I try to access a private route in my API (a route that needs authentication) with an invalid JWT Token, I get this response :
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}

Finally, when I try to access a private route in my API with a valid JWT Token, I get this error :

Session was used while the request was declared stateless.

Some issues on GitHub or here mention that this problem comes from calling getUser() from the Request when the firewall is stateless.
The stack trace doesn't mention any custom Listener where I call getUser(), but if I put a dd(...), my app stops on one of them (it's not important but I don't understand it either).
The catched exception is UnexpectedSessionUsageException who is throw in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/AbstractSessionListener.php:224 :
if ($this->debug) {
  throw new UnexpectedSessionUsageException('Session was used while the request was declared stateless.');
}

I don't get that point... What is the relation between calling getUser() from the Request and the debug environment value ?
If I change my .env file to set APP_DEBUG=false, I no longer have the error.
Could this have anything to do with the Symfony Profiler ?

Files
Below, my security.yaml :
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:

  # ...

  providers:
    api_provider:
      id: App\Api\Provider\UserProvider

  # ...

  firewalls:
    api:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: true
      provider: api_provider
      jwt: ~

Below, my UserProvider :
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Api\Provider;

use Exception;
use App\Core\Entity\User;
use App\Core\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

use function is_subclass_of;

readonly class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(private UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user): UserInterface
    {
        throw new Exception('Cannot refresh user in a stateless application.');
    }

    public function supportsClass(string $class): bool
    {
        return User::class === $class || is_subclass_of($class, User::class);
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
    {
        return $this->userRepository->findOneByUrai($identifier);
    }
}


